# Hyphenation of words containing apostrophes

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

My question is plain and simple.

**Any way to hyphen words such as “Lor'themar”, “Kel'Thuzad”, etc.?**

Using `\hyphenation{Kel'-Thu-zad}` gives me this error, for instance when compiling.

```
Error in hyphenation.tex (line 37): Not a letter. l.37 \hyphenation{Kel'
                      -Thu-zad} 
Letters in \hyphenation words must have \lccode>0. 
Proceed; I'll ignore the character I just read.
```

I'd like to define a global hyphenation, but I don't mind using a local definition for each time I want to hyphen those (a bit tedious, but that'd do the job as well).

Comment: From your question, I am not sure if you are aware that you can write `Kel'\-Thu\-zad` in running text to get the hyphenation you want. It's a bit tedious indeed …

Comment: That'd do the trick. As I use ShareLaTeX and i know which exact lines are overfull, it's not a big deal. My problem will come when I code the book as ePub. But that's another story.

Comment: If you add \lccode`\'=39 just before your `\hyphenation` command, I believe it will not complain and it will do the trick.  I also believe it will not break much in the rest of your text...

Comment: Just a question, shall I added before every `\hyphenation`  with an apostrophe, or just one time changes every `\hyphenation` from there on?

Comment: It turns out that it's needed before every one containing an apostrophe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained in my answer to [Listings and Babel (with some languages) are breaking hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164084/), characters with a non zero `\lccode` are those that TeX considers as forming words, when hyphenation is tried.

Thus in

```
 ``the masters''
```

only `the` and `masters` are considered as words under normal settings, where `` ` `` and `'` have zero `\lccode`. If

```
\lccode`\'=`\'
```

(which is equivalent to having 39 after `=`) is issued at the top level, the phrase above will have the “word”

```
masters''
```

and TeX will happily hyphenate it as

> master-
>   s“

because this respects the rule that a hyphen must have at least three letters after it (in the English hyphenation rules there's `\righthyphenmin=3`) and the pattern `aster5` in `hyphen.tex` makes this into a very good hyphenation point.

For this reason, characters with zero `\lccode` are not allowed in `\hyphenation`.

My advice is to use a macro for those apostrophes and something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\?}{'\-\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}
\hyphenation{the-mar thu-zad}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0pt}
and Lor\?themar felt that Kel\?Thuzad's controlled tone
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

where the zero width `minipage` is just to trigger as much hyphenation as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the comments I realised the are **two** ways to accomplish what I needed. *In the examples I'll be using the word **Lor'themar***.

### Global definition (in the preamble):

```
\lccode`\'=39\hyphenation{Lor'-the-mar}
```

### Local definition (in running text):

```
[...] Aethas replied, and Lor'\-the\-mar felt that his controlled tone [...]
```

Both ways seem to be equally efficient (apparently using `\lccode`\=`\` may have [adverse effects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164084/listings-and-babel-with-some-languages-are-breaking-hyphenation), as pointed out by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)). But for convenience (not only I'm writing the text in LaTeX but also making an ePub version) **I'm using the first method: the global definition.**

Comment: Setting ``\lccode`\=`\`` may have adverse effects, see [`listings` and `babel` with some languages are breaking hyphenation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164084/).

Comment: @egreg I have a question. I've noticed that if I write `\lccode`\'=39` in a separate line I can define as much `\hyphenation{}` for words containing apostrophes. However, If done as in the example (i.e., `\lccode`\'=39\hyphenation{Lor'-the-mar}`) I have to write `\lccode`\'=39` before each line, which makes me think it only affects that specific word.

Is this correct? Does this method avoid the adverse effects you linked out?

Comment: Once you set ``\lccode`\'=39``, the apostrophe is available inside `\hyphenation`, but it also becomes a "word making" character, as explained in my answer to the linked question. If you don't fear about this problem (but you should, depending on how apostrophes are used in the document language), you don't need to repeat the declaration for every `\hyphenation` command; actually you can have a space separated list of words in a single `\hyphenation` command.

Comment: Will I experience any problems when using English in `babel`? I actually don't mind using the second method, it's just a bunch of words in a very specific location in the text, but the first is *easier* to implement.

Comment: Closing double quotes might trigger unwanted hyphenation. For instance `masters''` might be hyphenated `master-s''`. It won't happen if you use UTF-8 and input it as `masters”`