# Hyphenation, apostrophes and a bi-language document

Tags: babel, hyphenation

It would appear pdflatex (with [frenchb,english]{babel}) does not do hyphenation of words with an apostrophe.

For example, I wrote "l'arithmétique" which was not hyphened, and the commands `\showhyphens{arithmétique} \showhyphens{l'arithmétique}` give
`ari-thmé-tique` and `l'arithmétique`.

I read the question *[Hyphenation of words containing apostrophes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165020)* and while very interesting, I am not inclined to define hyphenation for all words which might be used with apostrophes, especially when another hyphenation might (very, very low chance...) be used elsewhere in the document. I liked the adapted suggestion `\newcommand{\?}{'\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}` from egreg in the topic, but futhermore I'd like to be able to type an apostrophe to get an apostrophe...

Comment: I get `l'arith-mé-tique`; are you perhaps using `\showhyphens` before `\begin{document}`? Or perhaps you don't load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: I put the showhyphens just before the occurrence of "l'arithmétique" which is not hyphened. I use

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    %% fonts
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel} 
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{aecompl}

Comment: Please add *to your question* a minimal example of code showing the issue. And *don't* load `aecompl`.

Comment: Hinted by your comment, I tried disabling each of those packages one by one, but with no changes. I checked having latest babel, and I'm quite lost here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enter `\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel}` your document is considered as written mainly in (American) English. You should write `\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}` or better `\usepackage[english,french]{babel}` as recommended by Daniel Flipo, author of the frenchb module.